# Can not install datatable library using pip

Tags: python, datatable

Ive tried using pip to install Datatables and i get the following error.

```
NameError: name 'msvc_path' is not defined
      [end of output]
    
      note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
    error: metadata-generation-failed
    
    × Encountered error while generating package metadata.
    ╰─> See above for output.
    
    note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
    hint: See above for details.
```

Im on windows 11 using Python 3.10.9

I cant see alternate download methods on the documentation

Answer (score 1):

YEP...I ran into the same issue. What you *can* do is download the latest dev version.

Go to https://ci.appveyor.com/project/h2oops/datatable/history

Click on the name of the top green row

Click on "Image: Visual Studio 2019"

On the right side, right above the blue console, you'll see tabs. Click on "Artifacts"

Then right-click the correct python version, p310, and "copy link address".

Go into terminal and `pip install *paste the url*`.

This is also such a headache vs just using pandas. Maybe consider Modin which is like pandas but with automatic parallel processing. And parquet files built in.

Comment: Thanks for the advice on using modin, i think i'm going to go with that because this is such a headache. The only reason i was looking at datatables was my dataset was too large for my memory so pandas may be an issue.